# How to update text in window using .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval, var

I am making a very simple page that just counts how many seconds the user has had the tab open. In the console the seconds update, but on the page in the browser, it ain't.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Counter</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.seconds = document.getElementById('counts');
      var count = setInterval('counter()', 1000);

      function counter(){
        console.log(seconds)
        document.getElementById('counts').innerHTML = window.seconds + 1;
      }

    </script>
    <style>
      h2 {
        text-align:center;
        color:#032441;
        font-family:monospace;
      }
      div {
        text-align:center;
        color:#032441;
        font-size:70px;
        font-family:monospace;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#EBE9BD"
    </script>

    <h2>
      You have been on this page for
    </h2>
    <div id="counts">
      0
    </div>
    <h2>
      seconds.
    </h2>

  </body>
 </html>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: In order to change the text of a DOM element, you should use the [innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) attribute. Take a look at that and see if you can figure this out.

Comment: In the code you provided, you're not updating the value of `#counts`, it's not a syntax error, it's code that is missing.

Comment: So I added document.getElementById('counts').innerHTML = window.seconds + 1; but on the browser it just goes to one and then stops, and the colsole updates every second with 'null'. Is this because I didn't update the variable 'window.seconds'? (code link is updated)   [update, I got it]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The variable `seconds` is declared too soon before the element is even rendered, that's why I added the `window.onload` wrapper to your code.
2. You need to use `innerHTML` to change the content of a `div` element.
3. Not related, but you can also style the `body` tag via CSS rule.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Counter</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function () {
        var seconds = document.getElementById('counts');
        var count = setInterval(counter, 1000);

        function counter(){
          var newCount = Number(seconds.innerHTML) + 1
          console.log(newCount);
          seconds.innerHTML = newCount;
        }
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      body {
        backgroundColor: "#EBE9BD";
      }
      h2 {
        text-align: center;
        color: #032441;
        font-family: monospace;
      }
      div {
        text-align: center;
        color: #032441;
        font-size: 70px;
        font-family: monospace;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>
      You have been on this page for
    </h2>
    <div id="counts">
      0
    </div>
    <h2>
      seconds.
    </h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To access the "body" of an Element you have to access it via `element.innerHTML` which in your case would look like `window.seconds.innerHTML = window.seconds.innerHTML + 1`

EDIT: But that won't fix your problem.

1. Your script does not detect the `<div id="counts">` element, since it has not been loaded yet, you can fix this by moving the script after the div
2. Since `innerHTML` returns a string, performing `+` will attach both strings and your seconds will look like *011111111* So you'll have to parse it to a string via `parseInt(window.seconds.innerHTML)`

So changing 
`window.seconds = window.seconds + 1`
to
`window.seconds.innerHTML = parseInt(window.seconds.innerHTML) + 1;`

and moving the script tag at the very bottom, should to the trick

Comment: This: window.seconds.innerHTML = window.seconds.innerHTML + 1 appends 1 after the innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.seconds = document.getElementById('counts');
    setInterval('counter()', 1000);

    function counter(){
        console.log(seconds.innerHTML);
        window.seconds.innerHTML++;
    }
</script>
```

Bare in mind that 'counts' is not yet defined as soon as the script runs.